# Is there an analogue of Bass-Papp theorem for Projective modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, projective-module, injective-module

The Bass-Papp theorem for injective modules states that

> If $R$ is a commutative ring such that every direct sum of injective $R$ modules is injective then $R$ is Noetherian.

Is there an analogue of this theorem with the word injective replaced with projective and sum replaced by product? More explicitly is there is theorem of the type :

> If $R$ is a commutative ring such that every direct product of projective $R$ modules is projective then $R$ is **________**. ?

Comment: It is important that Bass–Papp is an iff. Chase's result is also iff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The theorem is due to Chase (1960) and builds on Bass (1960).

Let $R$ be a commutative, associative, unital ring. $R$ has the property that every direct product of projective modules is projective if and only if $R$ is Artinian. Chase (1960, Theorem 3.4, page 467).

Let $R$ be an associative, unital ring. $R$ has the property that every direct product of projective left modules is projective if and only if every direct power of the left regular module $R$ is left projective if and only if $R$ is left perfect and right coherent. Chase (1960, Theorem 3.3, page 467)

- Bass, Hyman
  [“Finitistic dimension and a homological generalization of semi-primary rings.”](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1993568)
  Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 95 (1960) 466–488.
  MR[157984](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=157984)
  DOI:[10.2307/1993568](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1993568)
- Chase, Stephen U.
  [“Direct products of modules.”](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1993382)
  Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 97 (1960) 457–473.
  MR[120260](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=120260)
  DOI:[10.2307/1993382](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1993382)